# Node.js, canvas: Image given has not completed loading

Tags: image, node.js, canvas

I have view all related issues, but do not find answer.
When i'm using this code in node.js:

```
var canvas = new global.canvas(400, 400), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
global.fs.readFile('test.png', function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        var base_image = new global.canvas.Image;
        base_image.src = data;
        ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 100, 100);        
    }
    else
        console.log(err);
});
```

I'm getting error: Image given has not completed loading
When i'm add onload event, like this:

```
base_image.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
```

It's never fires at all. 
Please help me to find answer.

Comment: first try `base_image.on('load', function () { ... })`

Comment: I have try: TypeError: Object #<Image> has no method 'on'

Comment: issues [364](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/issues/364) and [289](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/issues/289) sound relevant

Comment: Yes, but they didn't help me. My machine works on Windows and other parts of canvas - lines, text works correct. Maybe i need some additional libs?

Comment: does it work if you use `var canvas = new (require('canvas'))(400, 400)` and `require('fs').readFile` ? i have never used `global`, maybe it is causing some issue? finally, make sure to check F12 console to see if an error is thrown

Comment: no such use doesn't work too, any errors thrown too.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Having the exact same problem.

Comment: No sorry, on prod servers its works fine, thats why i just forget about my local machine problem

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
img.src = buffer
img.onload = function(){ ... }
```

do the following:

```
img.onload = function(){ ... } 
img.src = buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issue every time when I tried to render the PNG image below onto the canvas.

[image]

I noticed that the rendering worked fine for other PNG images. So I used a hex editor (http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) to see what is different about the file.

The obvious difference was the header:

[image]

I removed the ancillary tEXt chunk, saved the file and re-rendered without any errors.

This fixed the issue for me. There might me other chunks that confuse canvas when rendering. It would be really nice to have some basic data cleansing there to save us fiddling around with binary formats.

See: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/289

Answer (score -1):

If you are on OSX and used homebrew to install the canvas dependencies you might need to run:

```
brew prune
```

Then run:

```
brew doctor
```

This will list any links that are missing. Follow the instructions doctor provides for linking. If linking fails, run:

```
brew update
```

Then run the link commands again.

After all this, re-install canvas:

```
npm install canvas
```

This should solve the issue if you are seeing it on OSX with homebrew.

Comment: If you are going to downvote an answer, explain why in a comment. This answer is relevant to the question given the information.

Answer (score -2):

The error speaks for itself.

The Image has not completed its buffer loading and you are trying to manipulate it while it's still loading - therefor you are getting this error.

You should bind to "onload" event and only then do manipulation.

Something like this:

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = image;
var canvas = new Canvas(img.width, img.height),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

img.onload = function() { 
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height); 
}
```

Please note that if your application won't enter into "img.onload()", it probably means you have problem with supported library of Cairo - In my case I was able to load .png files but .gif.jpg didn't work.

I had to dig deeper and install libjpeg-turbo.

On the other side, I've created a very simple visualization of ubuntu (with VM box), and it took me like 20 minutes to install everything on ubuntu and it works perfectly.

Comment: You don't need to do it for node-canvas Image object. It works different than the browser one.